# Throw exceptions forcefully in JUnit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, code-coverage

I was going to increase the code coverage. In the process, I was unable to test the catch block of a specific method. I was trying to force exceptions to the method call.

## RuleSchedule.java

```
public class RuleScheduler
{

    private boolean                 enabled;

    private Integer                 batchSize;

    @Autowired
    private ExternalService externalService;


    public void executeRuleValidation()
    {
        if (enabled)
        {
            try
            {
                StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
                stopWatch.start();
                externalService.executeRuleValidationForProposal(batchSize);
                stopWatch.stop();
                log.info("Total time taken for RuleValidation:{} for batchSize :{}",
                    stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds(), batchSize);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // System.out.println("~~~~~~CATCH~~~~~~");
                log.error("Rule exception :{}", ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I was trying different ways to throw exceptions to get into the catch block of the above code, but was unable to do so. And here is my Test class. Even the batchsize is accepting null values.

## RuleScheduleTest.java

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RuleSchedulerTest
{
    @Mock
    private ExternalService         externalService;

    @InjectMocks
    private RuleScheduler RuleScheduler;

    @Before
    public void init()
    {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(RuleScheduler, "enabled", true);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(RuleScheduler, "batchSize", 5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteRuleValidation()
    {
        RuleScheduler.executeRuleValidation();
    }

}
```

Comment: If ExternalService is a `@Mock`, then you cannot reason about what a real ExternalService should do with its `batchSize`. Instead you'll need to stub the method to throw the exception using `when` or `doThrow`, exactly as in [j_b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929142/1426891) (no relation).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to configure your mock `externalService` instance to throw an exception.  You should be able to then verify the interaction with the mock.  Something like the following:

```
@Test
public void testExecuteRuleValidation(){
       // configure your mock 'externalService' instance to throw an exception
       when(externalService.executeRuleValidationForProposal(any(Integer.class))).thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);

       RuleScheduler.executeRuleValidation();

       // now verify mock interaction
       verify(externalService, times(1)).executeRuleValidationForProposal(any(Integer.class));

    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error in that stubbing part. It says unhandled exception in this line `when(externalService.executeRuleValidationForProposal(any(Integer.class))).thenThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class);`

Comment: I added exception to method signature but while I run the test, it says `java: 'void' type not allowed here`

Comment: and in this line `verify(externalService, times(3)).externalService.executeRuleValidationForProposal(any(Integer.class), any(String.class), any(String.class));` externalService is not getting identified.

Comment: @DeepjyotiDe,  Why did you add the `any(String.class), any(String.class)` parameters to the mock set up of the `externalService.executeRuleValidationForProposal1 method call?  Based on your code in `RuleScheduler.java`, the `externalService.executeRuleValidationForProposal` only accepts a single Integer parameter.  Further, the mock will only be called once so the `verify` should only have a `times(1)`

Comment: My bad, I removed that any(String.class) and it is the same issue.

Comment: @DeepjyotiDe,  does your verify call look like `verify(externalService, times(1)).executeRuleValidationForProposal(any(Integer.class));`  I found an error in my answer and just updated it to reflect this syntax.

Comment: I was getting on that line